# jQuery - call the element this into another function

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery function :

```
$('a[name=pmRead]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parents(".pmMain").find(".pmMain5").toggle();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: 'pm/pm_ajax.php',
        data: 'pm_id='+$(this).attr('id')+'&id=pm_read',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#pmCouter').html(data[0]);
            //HOW CAN I CALL THIS HERE? I'D like to do $(this).parents(".pmMain").find(".pmMain5").append('ciao');
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see in the code, I'd like to recall **this** into the *$.ajax* function. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just store it in a variable, like so (named it anchor):

```
$('a[name=pmRead]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var anchor = $(this);

    anchor.parents(".pmMain").find(".pmMain5").toggle();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: 'pm/pm_ajax.php',
        data: 'pm_id='+$(this).attr('id')+'&id=pm_read',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#pmCouter').html(data[0]);
            //HOW CAN I CALL THIS HERE? I'D like to do 
            anchor.parents(".pmMain").find(".pmMain5").append('ciao');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save the object before calling ajax event like

```
var thisObj = $(this);
```

and use it in the function like

```
thisObj.parents(".pmMain").find(".pmMain5").append('ciao');
```